# compileReleaseJavaWithJavac error trying to release.sh my app

Tags: java, react-native, gradle

I'm trying to `release.sh` an app but it's returning this error:

```
> Task :react-native-camera:compileMlkitReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/myuser/project/node_modules/react-native-camera/android/src/main/java/com/google/android/cameraview/Camera2.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-device-info:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/myuser/project/node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/src/main/java/com/learnium/RNDeviceInfo/RNDeviceModule.java:368: error: cannot find symbol
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable P
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/Users/myuser/project/node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/src/main/java/com/learnium/RNDeviceInfo/RNDeviceModule.java:370: error: cannot find symbol
        locationEnabled = mLocationManager.isLocationEnabled();
                                          ^
  symbol:   method isLocationEnabled()
  location: variable mLocationManager of type LocationManager
Note: /Users/myuser/project/node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/src/main/java/com/learnium/RNDeviceInfo/RNDeviceModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-info:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I made a few searches and maybe this information can be helpful:

android/bild.gradle

```
buildscript {
  ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
      minSdkVersion = 23
      compileSdkVersion = 27
      targetSdkVersion = 26
      supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
      playServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
  }
```

My SDK Manager has

- Android API 28 (only platform + sources)
- Android 8.1 (only platform + sources)
- Android 8.0 (only platform + sources)

Any idea?